# Why is my recursive JS function only catching the first child of JSON input?

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I'm having a recursion problem in Javascript. I have some JSON that I'm passing to a function. I'm trying to turn it from JSON into Javascript objects. My problem is that the code only returns the FIRST CHILD, not the second (which is labeled 'dir3'). Does anyone have a suggestion? Thanks very much for your time.

JSON input:

```
    var dirList = {"name": "topdir", "subdirs":
    [
        {"name": "dir2", "subdirs":
            [
                {"name": "dir2a", "subdirs": []},
                {"name": "dir2b", "subdirs": []}
            ]},
        {"name": "dir3", "subdirs": []}
    ]}; //valid JSON
```

Javascript function:

```
getChildren = function(dir) {
    dir.children = [];
    if (dir.subdirs.length == 0) {
        return [];
    } else {
        for (i=0; i<dir.subdirs.length; i++){
            dir.children.push({text: dir.subdirs[i].name, leaf: false, expanded: true, children: getChildren(dir.subdirs[i])});
        }
        return dir.children;
    }
};
```

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer

Comment: I'll answer it in a few hours; SO won't let me answer it yet because I'm a new user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you declare the counter in the for loop as a local variable within the function.

```
for (var i=0; i<dir.subdirs.length; i++){
```

It was using a global variable `i`, which was causing the loop to end early (one of the other passes through the function had set it to 0).